# Putting PHP values in HTML

Tags: php, html, sql

I had a PHP page where I was echoing out all the HTML. After being advised that is poor practice, and that I should write out the HTML and only switch to PHP when I need it, I am trying to rewrite my form to adhere to that.

I've tried the following, however the $row array which contains the results of my SQL query are not being called correctly,

```
<?php while($row = $sth->fetch()){ ?>
<p>
<input type = "hidden" name ="id" value="<?php $row["id"] ?>"/>';
<p>
<input type = "text" name ="firstName" size ="30" value=" <?php $row["firstName"]?>"/>';</p>
<p>
<input type = "text" name ="lastName" size ="30" value="<?php $row["lastName"]?>"/>';
</p>";
<input type="submit" value="Update" />';
<?php } ?>
```

From my understanding as long as the start and end brackets are still in the right order, the above code should work, however it does not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forget to call `echo` for each reference to `$row` inbetween HTML code.

Comment: The advice you got did not go far enough. You should completely separate your HTML ("presentation", "template", or "view") from the data you retrieve from the database ("model") and the code that responds to the HTTP request ("controller"). And you also need to escape your strings for html. Database-fetching `while` loops should not even be in the same *file* as html!

Comment: @FrancisAvila I'd rather not throw slightly advanced topics like templating at a probable PHP beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php while($row = $sth->fetch()){ ?>
<p>
<input type = "hidden" name ="id" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"/>';
<p>
<input type = "text" name ="firstName" size ="30" value=" <?php echo $row["firstName"]; ?>"/>';</p>
<p>
<input type = "text" name ="lastName" size ="30" value="<?php echo $row["lastName"]; ?>"/>';
</p>";
<input type="submit" value="Update" />';
<?php } ?>
```

You forgot to put `echo`, without echo it won't print anything.

You have another option, which is:

```
<?php while($row = $sth->fetch()){
echo<<<HTML
<p>
<input type = "hidden" name ="id" value="{$row['id']}"/>';
<p>
<input type = "text" name ="firstName" size ="30" value=" {$row['firstName']}"/>';</p>
<p>
<input type = "text" name ="lastName" size ="30" value="{$row['lastName']}"/>';
</p>";
<input type="submit" value="Update" />';
HTML;
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Lior, which approach is generally considered better practice?

Comment: In my opinion it is just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use echo

```
<input type = "hidden" name ="id" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"/>
```

Also, don't forget to escape for HTML:

```
<input type = "hidden" name ="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["id"]); ?>"/>
```

As of PHP 5.4, the short method is always available, even if short_open_tag config is off:

```
<input type = "hidden" name ="id" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($row["id"]); ?>"/>
```

Comment: You can do php short syntax with 3 less characters. If you get rid of the two spaces, the semicolon ins't needed: <?=$something?>

Comment: @Ted [Using short open tags is not a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use). And what do you have against extra spaces? Readability is important!

Comment: I'm with @Jocelyn, I always use the long tags. I also have a helper class for encoding, so my code is normally `<?php echo enc::html($foo); ?>`